# "WARNING: JBIG2ImageReader not loaded." but [org.apache.pdfbox/jbig2-imageio "3.0.1"] exists?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, apache-tika

My project is building with Leiningen using the pantomime 2.10.0 library `[com.novemberain/pantomime "2.10.0"]` which is some Clojure wrapper for Apache Tika.  I ground through some documentation at https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html to attempt to eliminate WARNings emitted by org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler but one seems to persist.

```
Sep 06, 2018 1:59:25 PM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: JBIG2ImageReader not loaded. jbig2 files will be ignored
See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
for optional dependencies.
```

I am struggling to understand what else I have to add to my project.clj dependencies to get this warning to go away.  Why didn't `[org.apache.pdfbox/jbig2-imageio "3.0.1"]` satisfy the dependency.

The relevant portions of my project.clj's :dependencies are:

```
[org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.23.1"]
[org.apache.pdfbox/jbig2-imageio "3.0.1"]
[com.github.jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core "1.4.0"]
[com.github.jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000 "1.3.0"]
[com.novemberain/pantomime "2.10.0"]
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Are you trying to suppress those warnings, or to add support for JBIG2?

Comment: @akond I am trying to add support for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable these warnings you need to suppress them in Tika config file.

***tika.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <service-loader initializableProblemHandler="ignore"/>
</properties>
```

and then use this config file in your code:

```
(let [handler  (BodyContentHandler.)
          config   (TikaConfig. (FileInputStream. "tika.xml"))
          parser   (AutoDetectParser. config)
          metadata (Metadata.)
          stream   (FileInputStream. "resources/memory.pdf")]       
     (.parse parser stream handler metadata)    
     (prn (str handler)))
```

To enable support for JBIG and everything you should refer to `tika-parsers-1.17.jar!/META-INF/maven/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers/pom.xml` which holds all the references to the supported plugins along with their versions. Add those plugins to your dependecies.

For the `[com.novemberain/pantomime "2.10.0"]` you should go with

```
[com.levigo.jbig2/levigo-jbig2-imageio "1.6.5"]
[com.github.jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core "1.3.1"]
[com.github.jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000 "1.3.0"]
```

It works for Java 1.8, but I believe it won't work for Java 1.10, which has this new module thing now. One of these plugins doesn't support this.

Comment: Yep.  Replacing with [org.apache.pdfbox/jbig2-imageio "3.0.1"] with [com.levigo.jbig2/levigo-jbig2-imageio "1.6.5"] in project.clj did the trick.  Thanks

Comment: The 3.0.1 version is better than the 1.6.5 version. That version has at least one bug that will prevent an image from being shown properly. The current tika version is 1.18, not 1.17.